# Flash dump with encoded firmware

Tags: firmware, flash

I downloaded [firmware](http://blog.danman.eu/wp-content/uploads/lenkeng-new.zip) from 4MB spi flash in HDMI extender ([more info here](https://blog.danman.eu/new-version-of-lenkeng-hdmi-over-ip-extender-lkv373a/)). It contains following sections:

```
0x00000000 – 0x00024e03 – SMEDIA02 …….456789ABCDEF (encoded – some strings suggesting bootloader)
0x00080000 – 0x0016ee5d – SMEDIA02 …….456789ABCDEF (encoded – probably the main firmware)
0x00250000 – 0x00250200 – some zeroes with some data
0x00257e00 – FAT with webroot
0x00367e00 – FAT with config
0x003e0000 – MAC + 2 unknown bytes
```

I'm interested in first two sections. The first one seems to be a bootloader and the second one the main firmware. There are some other unknown parts in the firmware which might be some kind of a key.

Can someone please help decode those first two sections?

Comment: did you get the reference of the SPI flash ?

Comment: This information may be helpful: https://github-wiki-see.page/m/v3l0c1r4pt0r/lkv-wiki/wiki/SMEDIA